# Parsing names in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have the below names in my table. I am trying to parse the first, middle and last names out of these. But each one is different and I am finding the parsing difficult.

Sample data:

[image]

Below is the rexter link:

http://rextester.com/live/EAGN87986

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Given those inputs, what *results* are you expecting in each case?

Comment: You don't: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). You either need a very clever AI, code that has completed a lot of machine learning, or a real person. And all 3 of those are still going to make mistakes. When storing names, if you're ever going to need to split them into separate parts (or even if you don't think you will), design your DBMS so it does store them separately.

Comment: This is not a trivial problem. The best thing would have been to capture the name parts in separate fields. Is `Mill` and first or last name? You just don't know (and can't assume).

Comment: On top of everything @Larnu said: even if you had the world's best parsing algorithms for names, you'll find T-SQL's facilities for string handling woefully inadequate for implementing them. The simplest "low key" implementations would be a tuneable set of regexes, that you process using a CLR function, or else some script inside an SSIS package when you're importing data. Not raw T-SQL.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am just given with this data. The table is so old formatted that they are storing just names and not separate first/middle /last names. So I don't have any sample output data

Comment: So you're saying that you don't even know *what success looks like* here? If that's the case, what are you going to use to decide if any answer is *correct*?

Comment: Given the complexity of names, though, there's probably nothing *wrong* with storing "just names". It's exactly when people think names can be easily split into first/last/middle that things go wrong. You should first ask: "wait, why do we suddenly need first and last names -- let alone middle names"? (I have two middle names. I never mention them -- mostly because I don't like them, but even if I did the number of systems that can handle them is vanishingly small.)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have just added a sample data here and I am trying to break these names into first/middle and last name categories.

Comment: I mean, if ***you***  don't know what the correct answer is, how on earth are us volunteers supposed to know?`

Comment: Like @JeroenMostert I've got 2 middle names, and I've been given some "wonderful" names from tools/solutions that can "successfully" split my name into Title, First Name, Middle Name(s), Surname.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write several different parsing algorithms, for each of the various patterns you commonly encounter.

Each parsing algorithm should fuzzy score itself on the likelihood that it has a good match-- e.g. does it get more than a couple of letters for first name and last name?  Does the first name exist in a common first name database for your culture?  Does the resulting last name exist in a common last name database for your culture?  Is there more than one first name (from your sample data, grabbing multiple first names might be common and therefore worthy of a higher score).  Make sure each algorithm's scoring is weighted similarly.

Run each of your parsing algorithm on the text.  Then compare the self-scoring of each algorithm and take the highest score, and use the results of that.  This will take a some time to fine-tune for your data.  You can get fair to decent results this way-- but as other posters have commented, it will not be error-proof.